# R - Unit specific time trends in regression

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

In a regression I am trying to model unit specific time trends but I keep running into difficulties. 
In `R` when I estimate the model with unit and year fixed effects like `lm(y~x+factor(unit)+factor(time))` I get perfectly normal results. However when I try to do `lm(y~x+factor(unit)*factor(year))`I run into trouble as `NA's` are produced.

Using some mock data to illustrate:

```
# Unit of analysis are countries
country<-c(rep("Isthmus",10),rep("Nambutu",10),rep("San Monique",10))
ccode<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10))
year <- c(rep(2000:2009,3)) # Time
x1<-rnorm(30)*ccode 
x2<-runif(30)
y<-0.5*x1-0.3*x2+rnorm(30) # Outcome variable
df=data.frame(country,ccode,year,y,x1,x2)
```

Estimating the model using fixed effects for units and time, country and year respectively:

```
m0<-lm(y~x1+x2+factor(ccode)+factor(year),df);summary(m0)

# Part of the regression output:

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      -0.92780    0.68231  -1.360    0.1928    
x1                0.59290    0.10058   5.895 0.0000226 ***
x2               -0.36457    0.96036  -0.380    0.7092    
factor(ccode)2    0.95383    0.48675   1.960    0.0677 .  
factor(ccode)3    0.46050    0.46475   0.991    0.3365    
factor(year)2001  0.15222    0.87295   0.174    0.8638
```

No problems here. Now I estimate the model using the unit-specific time trends:

```
m1<-lm(y~x1+x2+factor(year)*factor(ccode),df);summary(m1)

# Part of the regression output:

                                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                       1.3408         NA      NA       NA
x1                                3.3104         NA      NA       NA
x2                                0.5239         NA      NA       NA
factor(ccode)2                   -2.0544         NA      NA       NA
factor(ccode)3                  -12.2971         NA      NA       NA
factor(year)2001:factor(ccode)1  -3.4409         NA      NA       NA
factor(year)2002:factor(ccode)1  -0.6348         NA      NA       NA
```

In this particular case the `NA's` seem to be the result of too many variables in the model as there are no degrees of freedom left. This same issue occurs when using a [larger dataset](http://emiguel.econ.berkeley.edu/research/warming-increases-the-risk-of-civil-war-in-africa).  I am not entirely sure what is going wrong here. I assume it has something to do with the way I use `factor` to model the unit specific time trends but so far I have not been able to solve it.

Does anyone has an idea on how to do this properly?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you want `lm(y~x1+x2+factor(ccode)*year,df)`, i.e. *don't* convert time into a factor.  R will only estimate trends for numeric predictors.  The way you have set the model up, there is one parameter per data point, hence a perfect fit/zero residual variation/`NA` values for the standard errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to estimate more parameters than data, i.e. `n < p`. In your example data set, you have

```
R> nrow(df)
[1] 30
```

data points and are trying to estimate 30 parameters. As Ben points out, you are estimated a different parameter for each year. If you want to assume a linear trend, then just have

```
lm(y ~ x1 + factor(ccode)*time, data=df)
```

or to include a quadratic trend

```
lm(y ~ x1 + factor(ccode)*I(time^2), data=df)
```